# Heroku unable to find spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.2

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, heroku

I've gone through the steps at the below link to create a spring boot demo app and deploy to heroku, but I am getting an exception when pushing to heroku:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-spring-boot-apps-to-heroku

The short exception is:

```
Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.2.
```

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. The error references java 8 some lines down. It turns out heroku configures java 8 by default. To change the java version, follow the steps here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#specifying-a-java-version

Basically, add a system.properties file to your project base directory and add:

```
java.runtime.version=17
```

To configure java 17.